# MYSQL Получить данные по максимальной дате создания и уникальным 3 колонкам

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Моя таблица]

Здравствуйте, у меня есть такая таблица

`id|raw_id|company_id|warehouse_id|balance|created_at
1 |     1|         1|           1|   4523|2017-03-07 04:32:11
2 |     1|         1|           2|   2123|2017-01-07 03:15:20
1 |     1|         1|           1|   4523|2017-03-07 04:32:11
2 |     1|         1|           2|   2123|2017-03-08 03:15:20
1 |     1|         1|           1|   4523|2017-03-04 04:33:13
2 |     1|         1|           2|   2123|2017-03-02 14:49:15
1 |     1|         1|           1|   4523|2017-03-04 08:58:23
2 |     1|         1|           2|   2123|2017-03-04 03:38:23
1 |     1|         1|           1|   4523|2017-03-04 04:26:30
2 |     1|         1|           2|   2123|2017-03-04 05:17:14
3 |     2|         1|           1|   1123|2017-02-06 04:33:13
4 |     2|         1|           2|   3123|2017-01-04 14:49:15
5 |     3|         1|           1|   6123|2017-02-07 08:58:23
6 |     3|         1|           2|   2123|2017-01-17 03:38:23
7 |     4|         1|           1|   1123|2017-02-27 04:26:30
8 |     4|         1|           2|   5442|2017-01-15 05:17:14`

Суть задачи в следующем:
Есть сырьё, оно лежит в разных складах, а так же может принадлежать одной из 2х компании, это таблица учёта остатков, а значит что строки могут быть практически идентичны НО у них всех разные даты, задача: 
получить строки с разными товарами, которые находятся в разных складах, которые, принадлежат разным компаниям, за максимальную дату создания(последнюю).

Что я только не пробовал, всё сводиться к тому что : либо я получаю только по одному уникальному сырью либо я получаю непонятный набор данных как на скрине.

Не должно быть больше 2-х Позиций одного товара, потому что пока что у меня только 2 склада

Пробовал вот такой скрипт:

`SELECT tt.*
FROM raw_availability tt
INNER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT raw_id, company_id, warehouse_id, MAX(created_at) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM raw_availability
        GROUP BY raw_id, company_id, warehouse_id 
     ) groupedtt 
ON tt.raw_id = groupedtt.raw_id 
AND tt.company_id = groupedtt.company_id 
AND tt.warehouse_id = groupedtt.warehouse_id 
AND tt.created_at = groupedtt.MaxDateTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно в строках с id 19,23,24 одинаковое значение в колонке created_at. На скрине не видно эту колонку.

Comment: Вот я простофиля, из сгенерированных требовал точности, вы правы, проблема была в дате, лучей добра вам, вы спасли меня =))